# crash after reading textfile to tableview

Tags: ios, uitableview, nsmutablearray, nsarray, nsbundle

I would like to read a textfile from NSBundle which I have saved before in Xcode to an Array, to fill the data into a UITableView.

I have a textfile with information like this "this;is;a;test" named cart.txt

Now I tried the following code, and I can fill it into an array, but if I trie to set the rows of my tableview to the array count, the whole app crashes.

```
NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:@"cart" ofType:@"txt"];
if (filePath) {
    NSString *textFromFile = [[NSString alloc]initWithContentsOfFile:filePath];
    lines = [textFromFile componentsSeparatedByString:@";"];
}
```

I can read the lines array like `textfield.text = [lines objectAtIndes:0];` to a textfield. everything works.

But If I trie to get my data in a tableview, or even set the rows count to `[lines count]` the app crashes.

can someone help me with that problem?

I hope so :-(

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What is the exact error on crash?  Show the stack trace.

Answer (score 0):

I guess it crashes because "lines" array is already released when you send "count" message to it. Try `lines = [[textFromFile componentsSeparatedByString:@";"] retain];` and release "lines" in view controllers dealloc method